# Cannot set dynamically text value in input after typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface

I have simple jquery call, caused by clicking "edit button", that opens dialog box with input (#folder-typed) with default text value of $keepTitle. It works fine, but when I type new value to the input, then close dialog box and re-opening it, second line of this code is like ignored. Value of text input doesn't change, and by default it gets value I typed previously.

```
$keepTitle = $('.nav-folder-text[pass="' + $to_edit_id + '"]').text();
$('#folder-typed').attr('value', $keepTitle);
new_f_dialog.dialog("open");
```

E: Attaching html

```
     <div class="name-container">
        <label for="name">Enter name:</label>
        <input class="text-input" id="folder-typed" type="text" name="title" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      </div>
```

As I said, when clicking "edit" though several positions it correctly changes default input value to passed title, until I change text input value with keyboard - then it remains last typed value.

Comment: can we see the associated html ,please

Comment: I have asked the same question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55070696/input-text-tag-after-typing-value-cannot-be-set
It turned out to be a Chrome quirk.

Answer (score -1):

It's not just second line of code is ignored, once the DOM is ready, it loads all the included and referenced javascripts and css in the browser to create the desired content/functionality.

What you're seeing is expected behavior from this jquery. Changing the value of your input box will result in a different value everytime that particular input box will be visible on the page.

Put that input box outside of your edit pop up and change it's value. You won't be able to get `$keepTitle's` value back in that text box until you re-load the page or run the javascript in the browser console.

If you don't want the input box's value to be changed, you can disable the text box by `$("#textBoxId").attr("disabled", "disabled");`

I hope it explains the behavior that you're getting on your page.

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) before attempting to answer more questions.