# input text tag, after typing value cannot be set

Tags: javascript, html, input, set

I have a text input correctly set in html.
When this method is called pressing a button:

```
this._searchInput.setAttribute("value", "pippo"+Math.random());
console.log(this._searchInput.value);
```

It works correctly, and input text fields shows the string with random number.
Alas, if I type once inside the input text field, all subsequent calls to set value are ignored. Method is called since console outputs the same value visible in text field.

Any suggestion? Is there a reson why after typing in a text field value doesn't get updated by code anymore?

I have already found a similar question but it went unaswered: [Cannot set dynamically text value in input after typing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49824633/cannot-set-dynamically-text-value-in-input-after-typing)

Answer (score 3):

You are setting the value attribute of the input, not setting the input's actual value.

This is the line of code you want:

```
this._searchInput.value= "pippo"+Math.random();
```

Comment: Yep this does the trick thx. But why then BEFORE typing the setAttribute works well?

Comment: I'd guess it's a browser quirk.  It doesn't work at all for me in FireFox.

Comment: Also, when watching the code with the inspector open, you can see the input's value attribute change with each button click.